# Request for Tag Burnination: [Review]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, status-murdered

[review](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review)

There is no good reason for this to ever be used, given the scope of our site and the rules outlined by our FAQ. Looking at the questions it's currently applied to, one is spam, one is closed, one is a borderline game-rec cornercase that we generally allow (a version comparison), and the last two appear to be misguided attempts by our own badp to make the tag mean... I have no idea why he used it on those two questions.

Please make it go away? It is a Bad Tag.

Comment: You can just do it yourself, I don't think anyone will mind. If a tag is used so rarely it doesn't really need special burnination.

Comment: +1 I was considering posting this myself.

Comment: Or we could make it so that the review tag automagically adds the post to /review!  *Retags all of Wipqozn's posts to include this tag*  :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went ahead and removed [review](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review) from the 5 questions that had it. It should age away on its own after 24 hours or so.